# regex for numbers placed either before or after a given string

Tags: regex

I have a set of strings like:

```
[
  "ERDF : EUR 2.7 million",
  "ERDF : EUR 961 000",
  "ERDF: 7 305 000 DKR (+/- EUR    974 000) ",
  "FEOGA: 40 826 EUR",
  "49 % of eligible costs",
  "ERDF contribution: 64%",
  "FEDER (Objectif 5b 1994-1996) 60 979 euros (400 000 FRF)",
  "FEDER, Objectif 2, 1994 - 1999: 1 116 000 EUR",
  "EUR 8.000.000",
  "EUR 7.200.000",
  "EUR 4.200.000",
  "4.2 million euros",
  "EUR 0.2 million",
  "EUR 0.6 million",
  "FEDER: 830 842 euros (5 450 000 FRF)",
  "EUR  7,220,000,000",
  "DKR 1 220 000 + DKR 1 380 000 ",
  "GBP 150 000" ]
```

Online at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tehCd3/5)

I would like to capture the numbers (with 'million' if present) that have `eur*` either as prefix or a suffix. The below cases should match the expression

```
10 million euros
EURO 5.000
EUR 100
```

My current regular expression works only if `eur*` is before the number

```
/(\beur[a-z]*|€)+[\s\d\,\.|million]*\b/gi
```

Comment: You have shown several different types of thousands separators here.  Are there any _other_ formats which your question did not cover?

Comment: What RegEx engine do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Answer**

I'd recommend something like

```
/(?:eur\w*|€)?\s*([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?\s*(?:eur\w*|€)?/i
```

This recognizes the number and the "million" as two separate capture groups, and matches each of your given examples:

- `EUR 7.200.000` --> Group 1 = `7.200.000`
- `euro 4 000` --> Group 1 = `4 000`
- `EUR 0.2 million` --> Group 1 = `0.2`, Group 2 = `million`
- `Main project: 300 000 EUR` --> Group 1 = `300 000`
- `1998: 43.000.000 euros` --> Group 1 = `43.000.000`

Here's a [live example at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0xfk5c/1) of the regex that you can play with.

**A More Complete Answer**

Now, that said, this answer isn't *exactly* like the original request, since it matches bare numbers as well.  If you need one that *definitely* only matches numbers preceded or followed by `eur`, you'll need to duplicate and split the regex, like this:

```
/(?:eur\w*|€)\s*([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?|([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?\s*(?:eur\w*|€)/i
```

This correctly captures all of your original examples above, but won't capture bare numbers.

I have a [live example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VrnNBH/1) of this form as well.

Here's the same regex matched against [the extended dataset](https://regex101.com/r/YSQ9dW/1) you provided; notice that it doesn't match francs, percentages, pounds, or any of the other undesirable values, but correctly extracts every euro.

**Going Beyond the Question**

As suggested by @blhsing, there may be some value in including `\b` word boundaries so that this *doesn't* match something like `Grandeur 100`.  Those word-boundary characters belong before the `eur` in the regex:

```
/(?:\beur\w*|€)\s*([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?|([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?\s*(?:\beur\w*|€)/i
```

**An Odd Special Case**

Radu asks why the example above doesn't correctly match this:

```
ERDF : EUR 2.7 million
```

Or, more specifically, he wonders why it results in a capture of just .  The answer is that regexes are greedy:  They capture from left-to-right, grabbing as much as they can as soon as they can.  So as soon as the regex engine sees `EUR`, it can correctly capture *that* as the answer, because we've allowed  to be a "number"!

The way to fix this is to require that every "number" at least start with an actual *digit* — starting with `.` or `,` or  shouldn't be allowed.  We can do that by extending the number part like this:

- `[0-9\., ]+` (one or more of these digit-like characters)

  - becomes --> `[0-9][0-9\., ]*` (*only* a digit, and then zero or more of other characters)

Thus an extended regex that doesn't mis-capture Radu's other example by being too greedy (and that includes the word boundaries just for the heck of it) is this somewhat ugly-looking beast:

```
/(?:\beur\w*|€)\s*([0-9][0-9\., ]*)\s*(million)?|([0-9][0-9\., ]*)\s*(million)?\s*(?:\beur\w*|€)/i
```

**Regex Learning**

How does this regex work?  It uses a few basic pieces that the original didn't:

- First, it makes extensive use of `(?:...)`, which is a *non-capturing* group:  `(?:...)` is just like parentheses, and groups things together for precedence, but it doesn't actually *capture* its contents as part of the output.
- Some of the versions of this regex also make some of the content optional using `?`.

Given that knowledge, we can break down the full pattern (copied again below) into its logical chunks:

```
/(?:eur\w*|€)\s*([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?|([0-9\., ]+)\s*(million)?\s*(?:eur\w*|€)/i
```

- **On the left-hand side:**

  - `(?:eur\w*|€)` first matches the `eur...` part.
  - Then `\s*` matches optional whitespace.
  - Then `([0-9\., ]+)` captures the number.
  - There's more optional whitespace: `\s*`
  - Then finally, we capture an optional "million": `(million)?`
- **On the right-hand side:**

  - First, we match and capture the number: `([0-9\., ]+)`
  - Then `\s*` matches some optional whitespace.
  - Then we capture an optional "million": `(million)?`
  - Then some more optional whitespace: `\s*`
  - Finally, we make sure that it's followed by `eur...`: `(?:eur\w*|€)`

Comment: This will match pure numbers without any `eur`, however.

Comment: I've updated it to include a version that mandates the presence of `eur` before or after the number.  It's an uglier regex, but it precisely matches the requirements now.

Comment: Thank you! I can see it does. I have two very good answers I will choose the best once I run it through my data

Comment: I would retain the `\b` in the OP's regex to avoid matching strings such as `amateur 1`.

Comment: You could include the `\b`, and it's probably closer to his actual goal to do so, but his requirement asked for `eur` where it's any prefix or suffix, so technically, `Grandeur 100` _should_ be a valid match :)

Comment: @blhsing can we see your regex solution?

Comment: it looks even better in the updated version (no, we don't need other currencies but euros). thanks

Comment: @Nordle I started writing one after I first commented on SeanWerkema's first attempt, but just as I finished it I saw SeanWerkema's updated answer, which was very close to what I had, so I decided to help him improve instead.

Comment: I expanded this out to include a nice educational section as well so that this is useful in case anyone else comes by with a similar problem.  Learning for the win!

Comment: @SeanWerkema Well the OP is quite obviously trying to match Euro currencies, so no I don't think the right answer should match `Grandeur 100`. :-)

Comment: @SeanWerkema Just saw your update. Looks good to me. Upvoted.

Comment: @blhsing dang, ok! 
Sean Werkema, nice regex and explanation!

Comment: @blhsing: That's the difference between what he _wrote_ in the question and what he _implied_ by the question, which is why I included both answers. It's quite possible that somebody stumbling onto this answer later might actually _want_ to match `Grandeur 100` for some reason, so it's worth including both answers. The `\b` is probably more correct for his needs, but who knows what a future reader of the answer might be looking for?

Comment: sorry if my original question was misleading. thank you @SeanWerkema. great answer and amazing explanation. I have learned a lot

Comment: why in `"ERDF : EUR 2.7 million"` it only captures ` EUR` at index 6?

Comment: Heh, that's an interesting special case, because spaces are allowed in numbers. I'll update the answer with support for that scenario, and an explanation why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this `((?=[\w\s\d\.]+eur)|(?=[\w\s\d\.]+EUR))(eur(os)?|EUR(OS)?|million|\s|\d|\.)+?(?=$|\(|\))`

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/t9XvNo/10)

Comment: This will match just about any string containing `eur`.

Comment: @blhsing I think this will.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very close to what I am looking for. I need to test it against my 3k strings. Here's an updated sample data https://regex101.com/r/t9XvNo/6

Comment: Now it will match any string with both numbers and `eur` in it, such as `12931 hello eur`.

Comment: Yeah I gave an answer for the sample

Comment: @RaduChiriac try this

Comment: Now it will match `eur hello 123`.